# Error:incompatible types in a java class

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

I implemented a java class but come up with two errors which I can't fix.
Error1:

```
incompatible types
Required: RandomizedQueue<Item>
Found:    Item
```

Error2:

```
can not find symbol
Symbol: valuable last
location:valuable next of type Item
```

```
public class RandomizedQueue<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    private int number=0;
    private Node First=null;
    private class Node {
        Item item;
        Item next=null;
        Item last=null;
    }
    private Node Random() {
        double r = Math.random();
        int n = (int) (r*number);
        if(n==0) n=1;
        Node ob=First;
        for(int i=0;i<(n-1);i++) {
            ob = ob.next;   //Error1
        }
        return ob;
    }

    public RandomizedQueue() {
        Node empty=new Node();
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return number==0;
    }
    public int size() {
        return number;
    }
    public void enqueue(Item item) {
        if(item==null) throw new NullPointerException();
        Node oldfirst = First;
        First = new Node();
        First.item = item;
        First.next = oldfirst; //Error1
        oldfirst.last = First;
        number++;
    }
    public Item dequeue() {
        Node ob=Random();
        Item back = ob.item;
        Node temp = ob.last;
        temp.next = ob.next;
        ob.next.last = temp;   //Error2
        return back;
        }
    public Item sample() {
        return Random();
    }
    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {       //Error:cannot find symbol symbol:class Itertor
        return IndepentRandomIterator();
    }
    private class IndepentRandomIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
        private RandomizedQueue<Item> iq = new RandomizedQueue<Item>();
        Node scan = First;
        public IndepentRandomIterator() {
            while(scan != null) {
                iq.enqueue(scan.item);
                scan=scan.next;
        }
        }
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iq.number >0;
        }
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public Item next() {
            if(iq.number==0) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
            return iq.dequeue();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomizedQueue<String> test = new RandomizedQueue<String>();
        test.enqueue("Luo");
        test.enqueue("Jiebin");
        test.enqueue("is");
        test.enqueue("genious");
        test.dequeue();
        test.dequeue();
        StdOut.println("Is it empty?"+test.isEmpty());
        StdOut.println("Size:       "+test.size());
        StdOut.println("A sample:   "+test.siample());
        Iterator<String> it = test.iterator();
        while(test.hasNext()) {
            String s = it.next();
            StdOut.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no stacktrace, looks like compile error...

Comment: @luojiebin What line are the errors on?

Comment: I recommend to get the basic java naming convention correct. Class names starts with uppercase, variable names with lower as well as methods. That would make your code easier to read!

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat you should read the code :) There are comments with "Error1" and "Error2" :D

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat The error lines have been pointed out with"//"

Comment: @WarrenFaith Good idea.I will do it from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first error, you are trying to assign `ob` a value of `ob.next`. `ob` is a `Node`, but `ob.next` is an `Item`. Obviously, an `Item` is not a `Node`, so you can't assign an `Item` to a `Node`.

The same thing applies on the line:

```
first.next = oldfirst;
```

`first.next` is an `Item`, but `oldFirst` is a `Node`. You can't assign a `Node` to a variable of type `Item`.

---

For the error `cannot find symbol symbol:class Itertor`. That is because you need to put this at the very top of your code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
```

---

On the line:

```
return IndepentRandomIterator();
```

The code attempts to call the method `IndepentRandomIterator()`. To make it call the constructor for the `IndepentRandomIterator` class, you need to add the keyword `new` right before `IndepentRandomIterator()` like this:

```
return new IndepentRandomIterator();
```

---

For your error on this line:

```
ob.next.last = temp;
```

The code attempts to access the field `last` of the object `ob.next`. I think you want to access the object `ob.last`. That will still be a problem, though, because then you will get the first error. Both `ob.next` and `ob.last` are of the type `Item`, but `temp` is a `Node`.

---

Near the end of your code, you try to use `StdOut.println()`. `StdOut` does not exist; you should use `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 2):

The first error can not be diagnosed as you did not provide the implementation of `Node` class

The second error:

You do not craate a instance of your class.

```
 public Iterator<Item> iterator() {       //Error:cannot find symbol symbol:class Itertor
        return IndepentRandomIterator();
    }
```

You must provide an intances to be able to return.

```
 public Iterator<Item> iterator() {       //Error:cannot find symbol symbol:class Itertor
        return new IndepentRandomIterator();
    }
```

Comment: I voted up as it at least explains one of two errors

Comment: @WarrenFaith *one of the five+ errors. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I get more than 2 compilation errors.

Firstly, in the first line of the class:

```
public class RandomizedQueue<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
```

is `Item` the name of an actual class, or is it a placeholder for a class?

If it is a class, then your first error is complaining that it cannot find the field 'next' on this class - maybe it's not defined or not visible.

If Item is a generic placeholder then you need to define RandomizedQueue like this:

```
public class RandomizedQueue<Item extends MyClass> implements Iterable<Item> {
```

Where MyClass does have a visible field called `next`

Secondly, the code:

```
    Node oldfirst = First;
    First = new Node();
    First.item = item;
    First.next = oldfirst; //Error1
```

It seems to my that you are trying to cast a Node into an Item. But exactly what is an Item, and has it got anything to do with a Node?

I can't see what you are trying to do here.
It looks like you don't really understand [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), and you really do need to understand it before you can start using generics.